# Coded UI Test and Firefox 35.0.1 Issue

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to use microsoft coded ui tests with firefox. This was NOT an issue until Firefox 35.0.1 came out.

Skip to the bottom if you want to know the issue more than the why am I doing it this way:

Why I'm not using Selenium:

With Selenium, when Firefox launches a web driver, it loses it's previous states/cookie settings. I could of course import a cookie. The problem is that if I have multiple users running the test, they'd either have to set up individual lines of code to import their own specific cookie from their own path. This could become a dangerous game if a user decides to use someone elses cookie.

Why I'm using Coded UI Tests:

Certain applications I am running work exclusively with IE and others work exclusively with Firefox. Since I can't record the instances in IE with selenium, I have to should utilize a coded ui test anyway. I could of course also use watin. But at some point, why run Selenium, and watin when I can instead JUST use a coded ui test. Additionally, when going to the url for login with a coded ui test, FF is setup to save my password and cookie. therefore, the user can save their own password/cookie on each machine and just change the input for username which comes via excel spreadsheet. Everyone gets their own test, and no security issues.

---

The issue:
Since Coded UI tests don't recognize Firefox as a browser, it recognizes Firefox as a windows application. Therefore, edits and buttons in firefox are considered WinEdit and WinButton for firefox while internet explorer uses HtmlEdit and HtmlButton.
When Firefox put out an update, the coded ui test stopped recognizing certain objects in the firefox window. When trying to manually highlight objects/words with the test builder, it puts the blue box at the head of the web page instead of over what I'm clicking selecting. When hardcoding things to select, it doesn't recognize them. Is anyone aware of a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Recording on Firefox/Chrome is not supported by Coded UI. You can record your test in IE and Play it across Firefox/Chrome using Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing which can be found here https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d